# Strange setMilliseconds behavior during daylight saving transition

Tags: javascript, dst

This is the current time according to my dev console (in an Electron app, but the same thing happened in latest Firefox):

```
-> new Date()
<- Sun Oct 25 2020 03:16:02 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

At 3 AM, the clocks here were rewound by 1 hour due to the daylight saving time transition. Therefore the 2 AM to 3 AM hour happened twice.

I noticed some code misbehaving in this hour, and have tracked it down to the following odd behavior:

```
-> new Date(1603587532000).getTime()
<- 1603587532000
-> new Date(1603587532000 + 3600000).getTime()
<- 1603591132000
```

So far everything makes sense - that's exactly what should happen. But:

```
-> new Date(1603587532000).setMilliseconds(1)
<- 1603587532001
-> new Date(1603587532000 + 3600000).setMilliseconds(1)
<- 1603587532001
```

(Note that `setMilliseconds` returns the ["number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the updated date"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds)).

I am aware that [dealing with time is hard](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca), especially around non-unique points in time. Nevertheless, I am very surprised that adjusting the millisecond value of a date completely changes the interpretation of being before/after the clock change. What's the explanation for this?

Comment: yeah, odd things do happen in firefox and chrome and nodejs around that time

Comment: works fine when you use `.setUTCMilliseconds` though